# Garden hose spins but does not unscrew

Tags: screws, hose, dehumidifier

I am trying to detach a garden hose that is presently hooked to a dehumidifier. It spins freely but will not unscrew itself. Any idea what to do? Here is a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The knurled portion of the fitting is the part that unscrews. The longer brass-colored portion should be held stationary, perhaps with pliers while loosening, perhaps with another set of pliers, the knurled portion. This should allow you to release the hose.